# Instruct Jacoco and Coveralls to ignore some files from the report

Tags: java, maven, jacoco-maven-plugin, coveralls

I use Coveralls in a Java project with Maven to create a coverage report for my project and I want to avoid some classes from being included in the coverage computation.

Now, I think that I the build phase I can exlcude the class, e.g. `MyClassTest.java` as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*MyClassTest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eluder.coveralls</groupId>
    <artifactId>coveralls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Anyway, the coverage doesn't decrease, so I guess that the class `MyClass` is still computed from the Jacoco report.

In the travis file I call the report phase as follows:

```
- mvn clean test jacoco:report coveralls:report
```

Any idea?

Comment: Could you try with `<exclude>**/*MyClassTest</exclude>` (without `.java`)?

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for the suggestion. I tried, but doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, so another try :) `<exclude>**/*MyClassTest.class</exclude>` or even `<exclude>**/*MyClassTest*</exclude>`

Comment: No, nothing! May it be that the configuration is in the wrong place?

Comment: I also added how I call the module. Maybe I don't call test from the jacoco plugin?

Answer (score 1):

My bad!

First the `.java` has to be removed and replace with `.class` as correctly suggested by [Tunaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki).

Second, I don't have to exclude the test class, but the class that I don't want to measure in the coverage!
So it is:

```
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*MyClass</exclude>
    </excludes>
```

instead of

```
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*MyClassTest.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
```